# why tensorrt optimized pb can not be deployed by tf-serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorrt

I am using tensorrt to accelerate inference speed of Tacotron2 model. I used

tensorrt 5.0.2.6 version and tensorflow 1.13.0.rc0 version.

I convert savedmodel to tftrt savedmodel using the tensorrt api below:

```
trt.create_inference_graph(
input_graph_def=None,
outputs=None,
max_batch_size=32,
input_saved_model_dir=os.path.join(args.export_dir, args.version),
output_saved_model_dir=args.output_saved_model_dir,
precision_mode=args.precision_mode)
```

The outputed `tensorrt_savedmodel.pb` can not be imported into tensorboard for view but `tensorrt_savedmodel.pb` can be deployed with tf-serving.

However, when client request the tf-serving using grpc there is an error:

```
<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
details = "The TF function for the TRT segment could not be empty
 [[{{node model/inference/prenet/TRTEngineOp_33}}]]"
debug_error_string = " 
{"created":"@1572417319.714936208","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:192.168.23.17:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"The TF function for the TRT segment could not be empty\n\t [[{{node model/inference/prenet/TRTEngineOp_33}}]]","grpc_status":3}
```

any solutions about this issue?

Comment: you can use tensorRT server instead of tf-serving for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow saved model also provides a formal and consistent way to use tensorrt. You can try to convert it with the saved_model_cli and then deploy to tf-serving.

```
usage: saved_model_cli convert [-h] --dir DIR --output_dir OUTPUT_DIR
                               --tag_set TAG_SET
                               {tensorrt} ...

Usage example:
To convert the SavedModel to one that have TensorRT ops:
$saved_model_cli convert \
   --dir /tmp/saved_model \
   --tag_set serve \
   --output_dir /tmp/saved_model_trt \
   tensorrt

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --dir DIR             directory containing the SavedModel to convert
  --output_dir OUTPUT_DIR
                        output directory for the converted SavedModel
  --tag_set TAG_SET     tag-set of graph in SavedModel to convert, separated by ','

conversion methods:
  valid conversion methods

  {tensorrt}            the conversion to run with the SavedModel
```